# How to change the text color of text input in react native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, native-base

The placeholder of the input is green but I want also make the green text input  (when I am typing the text text color shows black which is not visible enough in my UI). How can I make it Green as well?

Comment: Please provide some code to show what you tried so far. Check [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how you can ask a good question. Check [style prop](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#style) for `TextInput` on how to customize your input.

Comment: is your problem solved?

Comment: Are you using native base?

Comment: Just in case if anyone trying to change the colour of the placeholder. To change color of the placeholder adds props called placeholderTextColor = "grey".

Answer (score 29):

add `color: 'green';` in your `TextInput` style will change the color

```
<TextInput style={styles.textInput} />

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 textInput: {
  color: 'green',
 },
});`
```

in `native-base` you will need to take care also of theming [see docs](https://docs.nativebase.io/Customize.html#theaming-nb-headref)

Comment: did you changed the theme colors?

Answer (score 13):

Simply create a style for your input and set color as green

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    textInputStyle: {
    color: 'green',
    }
});
```

and assign it to your textInput

```
<TextInput 
    style={styles.textInputStyle}
    placeholderTextColor='green'
    underlineColorAndroid='green' />
```

Answer (score 6):

If you want to change the TextInput colour add a **color** in styles.

below is the example give you the TextInput color as blue:

```
export default class UselessTextInput extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { text: 'Useless Placeholder' };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TextInput
        style=
        {{
          height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1, color : "blue"
        }}
        onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
        value={this.state.text}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

after trying many different solutions, I implemented a custom TextInput component where I placed a Text component that changes the color as a background and a TextInput over it that has a transparent font color. I hope this issue can be fixed soon in a better way.

```
updateText(v) {
  const { onChange } = this.props;
  this.setState({ text: v});
  onChange(v);
}
render() {
  const { changeColor } = this.props;
  const { text } = this.state;
  return  <View style={{ position: 'relative', flex: 1 }}>
            <Text style={ [ { flex: 1, position: 'absolute', zIndex: 1 }, changeColor? { color: red } : null ]}>
              {text}
            </Text>
            <RTextInput
              onChangeText={v => this.updateText(v)}
              style={[{ flex: 1, color: 'transparent', zIndex: 100 }]}
              {...props}
            />
          </View>
}
```

Comment: I had to use linear gradient text component instead of simple text. this saved my day!

Answer (score 3):

```
//Here is my input text 

<TextInput
            style={styles.txtinp1}
            placeholder="Password"
            placeholderTextColor={"grey"}
          />

// here are my styles you just need to add color in styles 


txtinp1: {
    backgroundColor: "#000000",
    height: "15%",
    width: "90%",
    marginBottom: 10,
    borderRadius: 25,
    paddingLeft: 20,
    color: "grey",
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

you can set the color props just like placeholderTextColor, though color is not a props displayed in documents, but it works in rn 0.61.5

```
<TextInput color='#FEFFFF' />
```